# How do I perform a complete Load Test process with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am new to using JMeter and have developed a basic test plan with HTTP Sampler and a few listeners. Please run me through the entire process of how I can start after opening JMeter ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no right answer for this, it depends what you're wanting to achieve. I'd suggest starting with the best practices: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

And also look at building a web test plan: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

I would look at the Graphs Generator listener - https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/ - use these graphs to make sure you're making the number of transactions that you would expect in your tests.

Basically - the documentation is your friend. I took time to read what each controller, listener and sampler was doing and decided how to implement these myself. There was some trial and error. JMeter is an easy tool to pick up and use but there's a LOT of depth to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is great that you are writing answers to questions but please read the [help] center pages about what sort of questions are on-topic here. This question is asking for a tutorial on how to do something and that is explicitly off-topic here. Your answer is good but both it and the question are likely to be deleted soon and so your wonderful effort will have been wasted. Please continue to answer questions but spend your valuable time on things that are on-topic

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ali1874 answer, I would suggest looking into how to run JMeter tests using command line. You can find more information at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui. With regards to reporting JMeter is able to produce nice HTML reports when using -e -o options http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test.

Also, with regards to Jmeter test plans, in my previous company we used to parameterize number of threads required, servers and other elements. In general structure looked like the one at [the example test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ7lU.png).

We had different user defined variables elements for different environments for faster test tuning. Also, we used *bzm – Weighted switch controller* (https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins)  to distribute load among endpoints by including HTTP requests from *Test Fragment* element so that we would not have to duplicate requests allowing to manage them more easily. You can check out full plan at here (https://github.com/gretard/testing/blob/master/00-jmeter/results/samplePlan.jmx). Please bear in mind that test plan uses  *bzm – Weighted switch controller plugin* and *jpgc - Standard Set plugin* which you can install  by using *Plugins manager* (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is great that you are writing answers to questions but please read the [help] pages about what sort of questions are on-topic here. This question is asking for a tutorial on how to do something and that is explicitly off-topic here. Your answer is good but both it and the question are likely to be deleted soon and so your wonderful effort will have been wasted. Please continue to answer questions but spend your valuable time on things that are on-topic.